# External crawl only gets dates if I map to String

Tags: search, search-results, date-time, managed-property, crawled-property

We crawl a site that is external to SharePoint. We have setup a lot of  settings on the site and after a Full Crawl, all the properties started to show up in the Crawled Properties list.

I than started mapping the crawled properties to relevant managed properties (as this is still in a test phase, all were mapped to Refinable...).

All the text properties (that have content) seem to be mapped correctly (both between the external site and the crawled property and between the crawled and managed property).

BUT! The fields containg dates show up empty if mapped to RefinableDateXX. I then tried mapping one of the date fields to a RefinableString and suddenly content was visible.

We really want to sort the external content based on publishing date, but sorting by a date in a String will not sort correctly.

Anybody know what I can do?

- Do I need to configure something on the external site? (Dates are presented in UTC format right now)
- Do I need to program something in JavaScript that changes the String to a Date object - and if so, how will I make a Display Template sort it correctly?